# How to differentiate Ajax requests from normal Http requests?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsf

I am using JSF framework in my application. I need to run a specific script before the render response phase in my Phase Listener class.

Condition for running this script is that, if the request triggered is a Ajax request i need to run the script, if the request triggered is a Http request i should not run that script.

Can anyone please help me to differentiate the requests recieved.?

Comment: Might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216173/differentiating-between-an-ajax-call-browser-request

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ajax requests have usually a `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` request header. In JSF, you can obtain the request headers by [`ExternalContext#getRequestHeaderMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestHeaderMap%28%29).

```
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
Map<String, String> headers = externalContext.getRequestHeaderMap();
boolean ajax = "XMLHttpRequest".equals(headers.get("X-Requested-With"));
```

Comment: if you are using RF then `request.getParameter("AJAXREQUEST")==null` will also work

Comment: Yes, you can also hook on implementation/library-specific parameters/attributes, but that tight-couples your code to specific implementations/libraries.

Comment: Where do ajax requests originate? JSF? JS library? Homegrown? Anyway, just determine the request headers to see if there's a viable key/value pair which differs between normal and ajax requests. Do `System.out.println(headers);` to see them.

Answer (score 4):

Ajax requests set a server variable `X-Requested-With` to `XMLHttpRequest`. You can use that information to differentiate between ajax and normal requests.

Answer (score 3):

```
private boolean isAjaxRequest() {
  PartialViewContext partialViewContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext();
  return null != partialViewContext && partialViewContext.isAjaxRequest();
}
```